# How to highlight the matches on search in GXT grid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a requirement where the Gxt Grid should highlight the matches as and when i type something in Text Box. Currently, it filters the value and displays only the row that contains the match. Can you please help me in highlighting the values on search.